# Main has no effect on JAR

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, jar, program-entry-point

I have the following code in main class it works if i run the program through netbeans. But when i open the jar made by netbeans it seems as if i had not written anything in main except the `new FormTTS().setVisible(true);`
If i write

```
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {   
        System.exit(0);
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"1125");
                new FormTTS().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

It is so strange that the program just exits by running from netbeans BUT not so in JAR, if jar is runned, it opens FormTTS!!!

I can't do without this, as i have some other code that has to be replaced by exit() and that needs throw exception(which i cant do from any other function or button than main())

I ensured that the jar is updated BY: 
I changes something in the FormTTS after placing exit in main; and i can see that change from the JAR.

**Editied**
What i did now is; i removed all the code in main and it doesnt work in netbeans(obvious) BUT FormTTS OPENS IN JAR!!!!
Ensured that the JAR is of that program by deleting the JAR, clean building the project and opening the JAR

Comment: Are you exporting to the JAR each time you make the change?  Is it possible they got out of sync?

Comment: Yah, i make it each time @UFL1138

Comment: Either your JAR is out of sync or it's not set up to run the class you think it is.  Find the manifest.mf in that JAR and compare with the name of the class you are changing.

Comment: @UFL1138 Sir i extracted the JAR through Winrar. there i found a manifest. here is its content: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 1.4.2_16-b05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: lib/freetts.jar
Main-Class: freetts.FreeTTS

Comment: Is code snippet above from class freetts.FreeTTS?

Comment: It is from extracting the JAR FILE from WinRar @UFL1138

Comment: In what class is that `main` method that you posted?  You didn't include the package or class name.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your JAR.  If you run `javap -classpath test.jar -c package.ClassName` you'll see the bytecode and it should look something like this if indeed your System.exit statement is being included in the jar file:

```
C:\Users\UFL1138\Desktop>javap -classpath test.jar -c test.TestByteCode
Compiled from "TestByteCode.java"
public class test.TestByteCode extends java.lang.Object{
public test.TestByteCode();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[])   throws java.lang.Exception;
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
```

<IMPORTANT_PART>

```
   1:   invokestatic    #19; //Method java/lang/System.exit:(I)V
```

</IMPORTANT_PART>

```
   4:   new     #25; //class test/TestByteCode$1
   7:   dup
   8:   invokespecial   #27; //Method test/TestByteCode$1."<init>":()V
   11:  invokestatic    #28; //Method java/awt/EventQueue.invokeLater:(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
   14:  return

}
```

Comment: Sir i dont know all this but to check the jar what i did was, i changed something in formtts just after placing exit in main and i can see that change in the jar .
So i think it should do all what you asked me to

Comment: Try running this command and see whether you see that `invokestatic` at the top of your `main` method.  Also, what command are you using to invoke it via the JAR?

Comment: Sir, i am not using any command i just go to the place where the files are located and then in dist and in JAR. I dont know how to run the commands you asked. and i want to distribute the jar, as it is so i cant ask them to run it from cmd, i just want it to work by clicking. Please note that i am 14 years old so pls dont get angry and explain in detail. Thanks

Comment: Run that command from a command prompt.  What OS are you using?  Can you add the contents of your Manifest.MF to the original question?

Comment: I am using windows 8; i dont know where the manifest.mf u talking about should be. Because i found one in Project Directory. But it has only this : Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 1.4.2_16-b05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Comment: If you have a JAR file that runs when you double-click it, it has to have a Main-Class defined in the manifest.mf that is in the JAR.  NetBeans may be taking care of this for you.  Can you provide some details on how you are creating the JAR from within NetBeans?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38442/discussion-between-ufl1138-and-daksh-shah)

Comment: ^ Please ignore this invitation to chat.

Comment: Sir i am on that chat page. Can you please talk there? Or please tell me what to do here.